# Changing text of label dynamically in jquery in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to learn Jquery. Having a problem in dynamically changing the Text of label.

Here is my code

I have

```
$db = new db();
$rings = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rings");
```

Now later on I am adding all the rings in a slider

```
foreach($rings as $ring){
    echo '<li> <input type="image" src="' . $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . '" name="checked" value="" width="150" height="150" /></li>';
}
```

There is a label somewhere in code

```
<label for="ringName" id="ringName" style="color: #701344; font-size: 10pt" ></label>
```

Now on clicking the Ring  I want to change text of label dynamically.

How can i do this in jquery.

I have done following things

Created a file : and added this in my main html `<script  src="js/jquery.rings.js"></script>`

Contents are

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function()
{
   $ring = $(this).val();
   $('label#ringName').text($ring['ringSetName']);
});
```

Also i changed the input to this

```
         echo '<li> <input type="image" src="' . $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . '" name="checked" value=$ring width="150" height="150" /></li>';
```

Howver on clicking nothing happens, how can i debug what is not working?

Comment: You do not provide enough information with your question to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @hakre there is no problem. i just don't know what to do in jquery to dynamically place text to img click

Comment: That's hardly too broad, that's the problem.

Comment: @hakre can u have a look at edited version

Comment: Debug it by playing around in the console. (Firebug in Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this: http://www.jqversion.com/#!/BvENIbA

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function(){
    $('label#ringName').text($(this).val());
});
```

Later edit: if you need other value from db to be added to the label you can use data like:

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function(){
    $('label#ringName').text($(this).data('my-info'));
});
```

HTML:

```
foreach($rings as $ring){
    echo '<li> <input type="image" src="' . $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . '" name="checked" value="" width="150" height="150" data-my-info="' . $ring['xx'] . '" /></li>';
}
```

**[See a demo](http://www.jqversion.com/#!/BvENIbA/1)**

Comment: That's great, however how can i access $rings[xx] instead of $(this).val(), because i might wanna do few other things instead of placing value

Comment: i have done all of this but nothing happens when i click!! can u check above what is wrong. Did i add the script file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You must have `ringName` field as a db column for this to work. Replace the foreach loop.

```
  foreach ($rings as $ring) {
    echo '<li> <input type="image" src="' . $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . '"'
            . ' name="checked" value="" width="150" height="150"'
            . ' onClick="js:$(\"#ringName\").text(\"'.$ring['ringName'].'\");"/></li>';
  }
```

Comment: what if i want to call a specific function instead of just ring label text change in jquery?

Comment: `onClick="js:functionName()"`

Answer (score 0):

You need unique Id of your ring element or Image which you added.

and then for that ring ID you can set onClick listener

```
$('#ringID').click(function(){
    $('label#ringName').text("clicked the Image");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2k5W8/1/)**

Comment: can u have a look at edited version please